# Ajax function doesnt complete before the second runs

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I got an Ajax function that looks like this

```
function PersonAtlLawUpdate(personRef) {
var selectionPanel = $('div#SelectionPanel');
var fromdate = selectionPanel.find('input#FromDateTextBox')[0].defaultValue;
var timeSpan = selectionPanel.find('select#TimeSpanDropdownList').data('timespanvalue');
var url = "MonthOverview.aspx/OnePersonAtlLawUpdate";
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    data: JSON.stringify({ personRef: personRef, fromdate: fromdate, timespan: timeSpan }),
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "JSON",
    context: document.body,
    success: function (atlError) {
        changePersonAtlStatusIcon(atlError, personRef);
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, errorThrown) {
        //alert(errorThrown + '\n' + status + '\n' + xhr.statusText);
    }
});
```

}

In one function I need to run this twice like this:

```
    PersonAtlLawUpdate($(gMarkedCell).parent("tr").attr("personref"));
    PersonAtlLawUpdate(pRef);
```

The problem that can be is that in some cases doesn't work 100%. The dom doesnt update in one of the functions. And I think it is because the other one "overwrites" it.

So how do I make sure that the second "PersonAtlLawUpdate" runs after the first one completes? Doesnt seems good to put a delay on it. And is it a good solution to set async to false in the ajax call?

EDIT, 
tride like this and placed a console.log in my success. But "all complete" will run first of them:

```
$.when(PersonAtlLawUpdate($(gMarkedCell).parent("tr").attr("personref")), PersonAtlLawUpdate(pRef)).then(function (){console.log("all complete")});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use a callback function so that it executes right after the first one has executed:

```
PersonAtlLawUpdate($(gMarkedCell).parent("tr").attr("personref"), function(){
  PersonAtlLawUpdate(pRef);
});
```

Or maybe you can rethink the problem, and come up with a solution that doesn't require calling the same function twice. Maybe you don't really need to do this.

Comment: The second one doesn't run. Doesnt metter if I make a console.log in there. Doesn't it count as another parameter when I put a function in my PersonAtlLawUpdate? Good point to rethink the problem with calling the same function twice. Will perhaps change to that later on when I got more time.

Comment: It's the same thing to send a second "personRef" as parameter and in my ajax function run it like this: function PersonAtlLawUpdate(personRef, cbFunc) {..... In success:             if (cbFunc != null) {
                PersonAtlLawUpdate(cbFunc, undefined);
            } ?

Answer (score 0):

I think what @Kyokasuigetsu suggests is you need to alter the PersonAtlLawUpdate method so that is accepts an optional second parameter: a callback function that need to be called in the success callback.

```
function PersonAtlLawUpdate(personRef, cbFunc) {
var selectionPanel = $('div#SelectionPanel');
var fromdate = selectionPanel.find('input#FromDateTextBox')[0].defaultValue;
var timeSpan = selectionPanel.find('select#TimeSpanDropdownList').data('timespanvalue');
var url = "MonthOverview.aspx/OnePersonAtlLawUpdate";
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    data: JSON.stringify({ personRef: personRef, fromdate: fromdate, timespan: timeSpan }),
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "JSON",
    context: document.body,
    success: function (atlError) {
        changePersonAtlStatusIcon(atlError, personRef);
        if (cbFunc != null)
            cbFunc();
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, errorThrown) {
        //alert(errorThrown + '\n' + status + '\n' + xhr.statusText);
    }
});
```

And than make the call as;

```
PersonAtlLawUpdate($(gMarkedCell).parent("tr").attr("personref"), function(){
  PersonAtlLawUpdate(pRef);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example will work fine if you `return` your `$.ajax` calls from your `PersonAtLawUpdate` function.

`$.when` needs a reference to the ajax calls, so make sure you return the `Deferred` (the ajax call) from your functions

```
function PersonAtlLawUpdate(personRef) {
    var selectionPanel = $('div#SelectionPanel');
    var fromdate = selectionPanel.find('input#FromDateTextBox')[0].defaultValue;
    var timeSpan = selectionPanel.find('select#TimeSpanDropdownList').data('timespanvalue');
    var url = "MonthOverview.aspx/OnePersonAtlLawUpdate";
    //SEE THE NEXT LINE
    return $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: JSON.stringify({ personRef: personRef, fromdate: fromdate, timespan:  timeSpan }),
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "JSON",
        context: document.body,
        success: function (atlError) {
            changePersonAtlStatusIcon(atlError, personRef);
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, errorThrown) {
            //alert(errorThrown + '\n' + status + '\n' + xhr.statusText);
        }
    });
}
```

**Use**:

```
$.when(PersonAtLawUpdate(ref1), PersonAtLawUpdate(ref2)).done(function(xhrRef1, xhrRef2) {
    //do stuff w/ results from both calls
    //if you return something from the server, 
    //the results will be available in xhrRef1[0] 
    //and xhrRef2[0], respectively (order they 
    //appear in the when(), not in the order they execute
});
```